# Display Bootstrap Modal on Browser Back AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to angularjs I have to show confirmation dialog on browser back,I am trying to do so but not able to achieve the required functionality.

Here is my **code:**

```
var previousUrl,backPress = false;
$rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function( event, newUrl, oldUrl ) {
    if (previousUrl && previousUrl === newUrl) {
        BootstrapDialog.show({
            title: "title",
            message: "message",
            closable: true,
            buttons: [{
                label: "ok",
                action: function (dialogRef) {
                    backPress=true;
                    event.preventDefault();
                    dialogRef.close();
                }
            }, {
                label: "cancel",
                action: function (dialogRef) {
                    backPress=false;
                    dialogRef.close();
                }
            }]
        });
        console.log("backPress"+backPress);
        if (!backPress) {
            console.log("backPress in condition"+backPress);
            event.preventDefault();
        } 
    } else {
        previousUrl = oldUrl;
    }
});
```

Kindly Suggest how to proceed next.

Comment: Could you add some more detail - what actually happens when it tries to run through the handler? What console logs do you see, are there any console errors?

Comment: @Starscream1984 the bootstrap dialog comes when it gets redirect to the previous page but it should actually come on back press.

Comment: I guess you might need a keypress handler which runs the routine when the keycode is backspace (8)

Comment: @Starscream1984 I had already added condition for back press based on url I am not sure why is not working,Is my approach not correct.

Comment: Check the caveats this guy writes in his blog post - http://www.markcampbell.me/tutorial/2013/10/08/preventing-navigation-in-an-angularjs-project.html sounds like your approach *should* capture the backspace, but it might not if the backspace actually goes to a different site, perhaps this is your issue?

Comment: @Starscream1984 I am able to do so if I use javascript alert but in case of bootstrap alert it fails